# Splitting html string using splitlines() still leaves space

Tags: python, html, string

I'm trying to split the below html string (example is shortened) into a list of options. 
(The html string was sent from the frontend via ajax using innerHTML on the select)

However when I use `str.splitlines()` I still get left with empty string and spaces.

Input:

```
<option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="1">Option 1</option>

  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
```

output:

```
<class 'list'>: ['', '  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>', '', '  <option value="1">Option 1</option>', '', '  <option value="2">Options 2</option>', '', '   ']
```

Is there a better way to split up string into a list of options?

(note I do have the option to change the front end too if that's the simpler approach)

Comment: Yes, use an HTML/XML parsing library

Comment: Like beautifulsoup, lxml, or the standard library's xml.etree

Comment: you want `[x for x in str.splitlines() if x]`, or a proper html parser

Comment: note: the last item of your list cannot be real: `'   ''`: 3 quotes no escaping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `str.splitlines()`  will not remove empty lines. The [method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) includes an example that illustrates what happens:

> ```
> >>> 'ab c\n\nde fg\rkl\r\n'.splitlines()
> ['ab c', '', 'de fg', 'kl']
> ```

The `\n\n` double newline separates 3 lines, one empty in the middle.

If you *must* split on lines and remove empty lines, leading and trailing spaces, use a regular expression:

```
import re

lines = re.split('[ ]*\n+[ ]*', inputtext.strip())
```

The extra `str.strip()` call removes the initial and trailing whitespace entirely, as you'd otherwise get empty strings at the start and end.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputtext = '''\
...
... <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
...
...   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
...
...   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
...
...     '''
>>> inputtext.splitlines()
['', '<option value="" selected="">---------</option>', '', '  <option value="1">Option 1</option>', '', '  <option value="2">Option 2</option>', '', '    ']
>>> re.split('[ ]*\n+[ ]*', inputtext.strip())
['<option value="" selected="">---------</option>', '<option value="1">Option 1</option>', '<option value="2">Option 2</option>']
```

However, for parsing HTML, you probably want to look at a library like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead.

Comment: Thanks ,that works, also a variation of the above comment worked too: `[x.strip() for x in str.splitlines() if x]`